# "Unable to resolve resource bundle" error when trying to run FlexUnit4 tests with IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flexunit

I am having a trouble to get IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2 to run FlexUnit4 tests. The tests won't be performed because of the following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve resource bundle "<some name>"
```

So I checked the build.xml whether the path-elements are set properly:

```
<path-element>resources/locale/{locale}</path-element>
```

This is working for the normal build process perfectly fine. Therefore, I am pretty confused and would appreciate any ideas that help to get the tests to run.

Answer (score 2):

The Flex libraries have resource bundles that sometimes need to be included. I added

`<Flex_SDK_location>/sdks/4.1.0/frameworks/locale/en_US`

to the build path and it fixed an "Unable to resolve resource bundle" error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I saw the suggestion in the other answer to add a path with the locale in it, and though my framework was set up correctly (and I couldn't manually edit any build path in the IntelliJ configuration), it did lead me to the problem.

Go to the "Flex" Facet in the module and click onto the **Advanced** tab.  The problem is if the **Non-default locale settings** is checked and blank, then it doesn't assemble the correct path and find your framework.

To fix it, simply **uncheck** the "Non-default locale settings":

[image]